# how to include html forms in a javascript file object in node js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am working on Node JS. For example i have some html forms and i need all these forms in a single js file which included in any other html file these forms should be diplayed. Can anyone please help me regarding this?

Comment: HTML forms should be included in HTML files, not in JS files.

Comment: You can use JSX , that way you can have HTML in JS file